# i have some url's ,whenthe urls is clicked ,we should know who has clicked and which url ,user has clicked in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some href link's to PDF, when the user login's using username and password and click's on the particular href links, I want to know which user has clicked and accessed which link.

Comment: You need to implement a hook in Codeigniter or some kind of middleware in another language I say to do that.

Comment: write a php script to handle the href links, take the user out of the session, and return the PDF. What's the problem?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

have you stored user details in session after login, if u have stored the user data in session it must be straight forward task.

In your controller

```
 public function pdfview() {


    $user_id= retrieve from session //get from session 
    $this->body['user_id'] = $user_id  // for passing data in view 

    $this->load->view('your_view',$this->body); //passing user_id to view

}


  public function viewpdf(){
   $url=$this->uri->segement()//url 
   $user_id=$this->input->get(user_id);

   //now you can know which user has accessed which link
   //you can store it or do as u please 



}
```

In your view 'Your_view.php'

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>your_controller/viewpdf?user_id=<?php echo $user_id?></a> // link to pdf for users and you can send other attributes accordingly to satisfy your need
```